# Can I cache OleDbConnection and keep it long time

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, static, oledb, oledbconnection

In static constructor I check if I can open connection with all databases and then keep a static copy of ConnectionStrings and afterwards when needed use it.

Now if I create

private static List < OleDbConnection > _connections;

and store all the open connections as open connections?
Can I use these connections till the application is on. Is there any harm in doing this?

Comment: Not best practice, but there should be no harm in it other than possibly having multiple files open on your PC (or where ever).

Comment: So best practice will be storing connection strings and open connectionstring everytime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is already done for you by the system using connection pools.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.aspx

> To deploy high-performance applications, you must use connection
>   pooling. **When you use the .NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB, you
>   do not have to enable connection pooling because the provider manages
>   this automatically.** For more information about how to use connection
>   pooling with the .NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB, see OLE DB,
>   ODBC, and Oracle Connection Pooling (ADO.NET) (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ole-db-odbc-and-oracle-connection-pooling).